# Ruby On Rails Spreadsheet - Validate File Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, spreadsheet

I'm using the rails Spreadsheet gem (http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html) to import excel data into my application.

I can get the Excel file to upload fine and use:

book = Spreadsheet.open filePath

to open the file

This works fine if the file is a valid Excel file, but if my user decides to upload a random image file or something else instead, I get this error:

OLE2 signature is invalid

Which is understandable.

I can't find anywhere a way to validate the file before I open it. I'd rather not do it by file extension if I can help it, does anyone know a way to try to validate the file by content type before I open it?

Ta, Jo

Comment: Why not validate *by* opening, and trap the error with a begin/rescue/end block?

Comment: Oh sorry, just noticed this comment, that's what I ended up doing! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to validate the file type, most of them however are by checking the file extension.

If you don't want to do that and you have access to the 'file' command you can try this:

```
class File
  def type_from_file_command
    type = (self.original_filename.match(/\.(\w+)$/)[1] rescue "octet-stream").downcase
    mime_type = `file -b --mime-type #{self.path}`.split(':').last.strip rescue "application/x-#{type}"
    mime_type = "application/x-#{type}" if mime_type.match(/\(.*?\)/)
    mime_type
  end
end

ruby-1.9.2-p290 :030 > a = File.open("/path/nube_minilogo.psd")
 => #<File:/path/nube_minilogo.psd> 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :031 > a.type_from_file_command
 => "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop"
```

Adapted from Paperclip.

Comment: A better way of doing this would be to have a conditional method that will open the file for streaming and close the pipe after the mimetype had been obtained if it didn't match the expected one. :)

Comment: Ahhh,I'm pretty new to rails and your answer reminded me of "rescue", this actually solved my problem as all I wanted to do was make sure it didn't fail if Spreadsheet tried to open an invalid file type.     
begin 
  book = Spreadsheet.open filePath
  //process spreadsheet
rescue
  //human error message
end